# Angr Use argv as initialstate

Tags: python, angr

I am currently trying to use angr, and I need to find a string "Done!" which results in the "good termination" of the program. The input is 32 bits and I need to know the input which leads to the "Done!" being printed.
I thought of using the following in my python script:

```
b = angr.Project('a.out')
arg1 = claripy.BVS('arg1', 32)
b.factory.entry_state(args=['a.out', arg1])
pg = b.factory.simgr()
pg.explore(find=lambda x: b'Done!' in x.posix.dumps(1))
```

In my current knowledge of angr, this should result in the path, wich leads to "Done!" being printed. Am I mistaken? With found[0] I could then access the result.
But angr leaves me with

```
<SimulationManager with 1 deadended>
```

as an output for my simulation manager. What am I doing wrong? Are there more requirements needed for this to work?

Apriciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: Can you share the binary here?